# Eigenvalues of matrix $A$ where $A$ is an $n$ by $n$ matrix where $a_{i,i+1} = 1 \forall i=1,2,...,n-1 $,$a_{n,1}=1$,Other remaining entries are $0$.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant, trace

Let $A$ be a $n$ by $n$ matrix where $n$ is odd and $n \geq 7$ , and $a_{i,i+1} = 1 \forall i=1,2,...,$ and $a_{n,1}=1$ ,additionally other entries are $0$, i.e. 
$$A=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
                    0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
                    0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & \cdots & 0 \\
                    \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
                    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 1 \\
                    1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$
Can $A$ have eigen value of $-1$, also can $A$ have an eigenvalue of multiplicity $\geq2$?

I tried that $Trace(A) = 0$ and $Det(A) = 1$ from the structure of matrix $A$ , i concluded that $0 $ cannot be an eigenvalue ,and from taking a particular case of $n=7$ I got eigenvalue of $1$, now how do i proceed ?

Comment: what is $a_{11}$. how can the trace be 0

Comment: $a_{1,1}=0$ since it is one of the "Other" entries, right?

Comment: @Upstart , since all the entries in the main diagonal is $0$ , hence trace is $0$.

Comment: @Laray yes it is $0$.

Comment: now it is clear it was not clear before the edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set of all the matrices which are just the permutaion of the identity matrix of order $n*n$ is isomorphic to the group $S_n$.
Consider your matrix as an element of $S_n$. The matrix can be regarded as the permutation ($1$   $n$ $n-1$ $n-2$.......$2$).
This is a $n-cycle$. hence its order is $n$. That means $x^n=idt$ where $idt$ is the identity permutation.

Hence your matrix has characteristic equation $x^n-1=0$.

If $n$ is odd then $-1$ is not an eigenvalue.If $n$ is even then  $-1$ is an eigenvalue. And since these are the $n$th roots of unity they can't be repeated.

Comment: can you give some reference this statement - "The set of all the matrices which are just the permutaion of the identity matrix of order $n∗n$ is isomorphic to the group $S_{n}$. "

Comment: any reference for the above statement ?

Answer (score 1):

You have $A = \begin{pmatrix} 0&1&0\\0 &0&1\\1&0&0\end{pmatrix}$ for $n=3$, right?

This matrix is the transpose of the [Companion matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix) of a quite simple polynomial $p=x^n -1$

Since the matrix has only a single entry in every row and column, it's orthogonal and it's eigenvalues are the $n$-th roots of unity.

Comment: You are right on that, I will change my answer. Thank you!

Comment: @Laray if you see the question carefully then here $n$ is an odd integer $\geq 7$ and we cannot take $n = 4$ here!.

Comment: Sorry, I read over that. It does not change the fact about the characteric polynomial or the roots of unity. This will, on the other hand, make it impossible to have $-1$ as eigenvalue.

Comment: It's the companion matrix of $x^n-1$

Comment: I hate transposing and weird indexing... You are right, I will correct that in my answer!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** What you are describing is a special case of a [Circulant matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix#Eigenvectors_and_eigenvalues). A general circulant matrix takes the form
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
c_0 & c_{n-1} & \dots & c_2 & c_1 \\
c_1 & c_0 & c_{n-1} & & c_2 \\
\vdots & c_1 & c_0 & \ddots & \vdots \\
c_{n-2} & & \ddots & \ddots & c_{n-1} \\
c_{n-1} & c_{n-2} & \dots & c_1 & c_0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
and has eigenvalues 
$$
\lambda_j = c_0 + c_{n-1} \omega_j + c_{n-1} \omega_j^2 + \dots + c_1 \omega_j^{n-1}, \quad j=0, \dots, n-1,
$$
where $\omega_j$ are the $n$th roots of unity.
What is $c_k, \, k=0, \dots n-1$ in your case?
What does this tell you about the eigenvalues of your matrices?